# Объясните как перемешиваются значения в цикле

Tags: c, циклы

Вот программа, я начинаю путаться и не понимаю, что куда переходит. Можете объяснить с каким-нибудь примером.

```
void newarray(int arr1[]);
int main()
{
    int array[5]= {};
    int i;
    printf("Enter your 5 - elements array: \n");

    for(i = 0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    newarray(array);

    return 0;
}

void newarray(int* arr1)
{
    int i, k, f;

    printf("Your array is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("[%d]: %d", i, arr1[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        k=rand()%5; 
        f=arr1[k];   //1
        arr1[k]=arr1[i]; //2
        arr1[i]=f; //3 не совсем понимаю, что происходит в этих трёх строках

    }

    for(i= 0; i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("[%d]: %d\t", i, arr1[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rand.htm

Comment: `k=rand()%5;` - вычисляется случайное значение индекса массива - от нуля до четырех

Comment: извините, не правильно отметила строки, уже исправила

Comment: эти три строки меняют местами два значения в массиве - с индексами `k` и `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`srand(time(NULL));` – генерирует базу, которую использует алгоритм генерации псевдослучайных чисел (функция `rand`), используя текущее время.

Функция `rand()` генерирует псевдослучайное число от 0 до константы `RAND_MAX`. Так как это число не должно быть больше 5, иначе мы выйдем за границы массива, оно делится на 5 и берется остаток (который всегда меньше 5) – `k=rand()%5;`.

Таким образом `arr[k]` – это случайный элемент массива, а в этих трех строчках –

```
    f=arr1[k];   
    arr1[k]=arr1[i]; 
    arr1[i]=f;
```

меняются местами два элемента массива `arr[i]` – элемент который берется из массива по цикла и `arr[k]`. В данном случае `f` выступает в роли временной переменной.

Comment: можете проверить всё ли у меня правильно  в цикле for в функции newarray поскольку я искала подобные задания и там цикл for написан везде по другому

Comment: @paiiiin с виду все правильно, функция сначала выводит массив, потом перемешивает его, потом снова выводит. Если работает – то все нормальной. Правда по правилам написания кода функцию newarray нужно разбить на 2 функции – одна перемешивает массив, другая выводит, но это уже другой разговор.

Comment: хорошо, большое спасибо